# Why is git not complaining about merge conflict?

Tags: git, branch, merge-conflict-resolution

I have two branches in a Git repository.

```
* 68d0cfc (HEAD -> master) Fixed error in makefile. Command rm is now erasing main.o, too.
| * a2dcb6c (temp_branch) Temporary commit to save progress.
|/  
* c86fd55 structs trans_table_entry and trans_table created. Functions get_trans_table_available_entry, create_insert_new_trans_entry and compare_input_with_trans_key defined.
* b8ba145 structs fsm_t and state_t created. Functions create_fsm, create_new_state and set_fsm_initial_state defined
```

In every branch there is a main.c with different content.

This is main.c from master branch.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "fsm.h"

int main(void) {    
    fsm_t *fsm = create_fsm("fsm0");
    
    state_t *q0 = create_new_state("q0", false);
    state_t *q1 = create_new_state("q1", false);
    set_fsm_initial_state(fsm, q0);
    
    printf("FSM %s\n", fsm->fsm_name);
    printf("State %s\n", q0->state_name);
    printf("State %s\n", q1->state_name);
    printf("FSM initial state %s\n", fsm->initial_state->state_name);
    
    trans_table_entry_t *trans_table_entry = create_insert_new_trans_entry(q0, "01", q1);
    printf("New trans_table_entry: \n");
    printf("    transition_key: %s\n", trans_table_entry->transition_key); 
    printf("    next_state: %s\n", trans_table_entry->next_state->state_name); 
    
    printf("trans_table_entry in fsm0's initial state: \n");
    printf("    transition_key: %s\n", STATE_ENTRY_TR_KEY(fsm->initial_state, 0));
    printf("    next_state: %s\n", STATE_ENTRY_NEXT_STATE(fsm->initial_state, 0)->state_name);
    
    char trans_key1[] = "0111";
    char trans_key2[] = "0X10";
    
    char *input = "01110010";
    printf("Comparing trans_key1(%s) with 0111: %s\n", trans_key1, compare_input_with_trans_key(input, trans_key1) == true? "Valid" : "Invalid");
    printf("Comparing trans_key2(%s) with 0111: %s\n", trans_key2, compare_input_with_trans_key(input, trans_key2) == true? "Valid" : "Invalid");
    
    input += 4;
    printf("Comparing trans_key1(%s) with 0010: %s\n", trans_key1, compare_input_with_trans_key(input, trans_key1) == true? "Valid" : "Invalid");
    printf("Comparing trans_key2(%s) with 0010: %s\n", trans_key2, compare_input_with_trans_key(input, trans_key2) == true? "Valid" : "Invalid");   

    return 0;
}
```

This is main from temp_branch.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "fsm.h"

int main(void) {    
    fsm_t *fsm = create_fsm("0s_1s_alt");
    //Initial state. No data.
    state_t *q0 = create_new_state("q0", false);
    //Last bit received is 1. Second last is 0.
    state_t *q1 = create_new_state("q1", false);
    //Last bit received is 0. Second last is 1.
    state_t *q2 = create_new_state("q2", false);
    //Dead state.
    state_t *D = create_new_state("D", true);
    set_fsm_initial_state(fsm, q0);
    char *trans_key = "0";
    
    trans_table_entry_t *trans_table_entry = create_insert_new_trans_entry(q0, trans_key, q2);
    trans_key = "1";
    trans_table_entry = create_insert_new_trans_entry(q0, trans_key, q1);
    trans_key = "0";
    trans_table_entry = create_insert_new_trans_entry(q1, trans_key, q2);
    trans_key = "1";
    trans_table_entry = create_insert_new_trans_entry(q1, trans_key, D);
    trans_key = "0";
    trans_table_entry = create_insert_new_trans_entry(q2, trans_key, D);
    trans_key = "1";
    trans_table_entry = create_insert_new_trans_entry(q2, trans_key, q1);
    trans_key = "0";
    trans_table_entry = create_insert_new_trans_entry(D, trans_key, D);
    trans_key = "1";
    trans_table_entry = create_insert_new_trans_entry(D, trans_key, D);

    char input[] = {'0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '1', '0'};
    if(execute_fsm(fsm, input) == FSM_NO_ERROR) {
        printf("%s working correctly.\n", fsm->fsm_name);
    }
    else {
        printf("An error occurred. One of the transitions was not executed.\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I already tried using different methods

```
git merge temp_branch
git merge -s resolve master temp_branch
```

This is what I get after merging.

```
Merge made by the 'ort' strategy
fsm.c  | 25 +++++++++++++++++++++++++
fsm.h  |  4 ++--
main.c | 57 +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++--------------------------
3 files changed, 58 insertions(+), 28 deletions(-)

Trying really trivial in-index merge...
fsm.c  | 25 +++++++++++++++++++++++++
fsm.h  |  4 ++--
main.c | 57 +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++--------------------------
3 files changed, 58 insertions(+), 28 deletions(-)
```

But the result is the same always: Git keeps replaces the content of main.c from master with the content from temp_branch without any error.
If the contents of the two files are different, why is this happening?

Comment: Note that the first three lines of your `git log -all --decorate --oneline --graph` output show you the *three* commits of interest here: the two branch tips *and the merge base commit* `c86fd55`. Running `git diff c86fd55 master` and `git diff c86fd55 temp_branch` will show you what two sets of changes `git merge` is going to attempt to combine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There would be conflict only if main.c:

- had been changed in both branches, since the `temp_branch` was created
- if changes are done on common lines

If not, changes from `temp_branch` are reported to `master`.

> In every branch there is a main.c with different content.

If the "different content" in `main.c`/`master` was done *before*  `temp_branch` modifications, then merging `temp_branch` to master would simply reports those `temp_branch` modifications back to `master`.